# Trying to make a function to find a specified target

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a searching function. But that doesn't work right everytime. Gives the right output sometimes tough. Here is what i did:

```
import random

def normal_search(l, target):
    # printing the list
    l1 = l
    x = ' '.join([str(l)])
    print(f'The list is {x}')

    choose = random.choice(l)

    if choose == target:
        index = l.index(choose)
        index += 1
        print(f"I found it! It's {index}. element.")

    while choose != target:
        l.remove(choose)
        choose = random.choice(l)
        print(choose)
    index = l1.index(choose)
    index += 1
    print(f"normal_search I found it! It's {index}. element.")

# creating a shuffled list of 0 to 10
a = []
n = 0
while len(a) < 10:
    n += 1
    a.append(n)
random.shuffle(a)

normal_search(a, 5)
```

I am trying to get the target as output. What is making the output wrong?

Comment: What output are you getting, and what output are you expecting?

Comment: FYI you should never call a variable something like `list` since that's a built-in name. If you tried to call the built-in `list()` function you would get an error. Instead, use a name that is not [one of these](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: How do you know the output is wrong? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

def normal_search(l, target):
    # printing the list
    x = ' '.join([str(l)])
    print(f'The list is {x}')

    while True:
        choose = random.choice(l)
        if choose == target:
            index = l.index(choose)
            index += 1
            print(f"normal_search I found it! It's {index}. element.")
            break

# creating a shuffled list of 0 to 10
a = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(a)

normal_search(a, 5)
```

As @FraRomee said, you are removing one element every step, suppose at first you have a list like: `[0, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 1, 8, 9, 7]`, and index(5) is 6 and you randomly choose an element: 3 and it is not equal to 5 and you remove it, then you have `[0, 6, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9, 7]` and length of list is 9 and index(5) is 5
and so on you choose 6 and remove it and you have `[0, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9, 7]`.

so if this time you select 5 correctly, index is 4 and it is correct for new list but is wrong for initial list and you cant use it for your own.

## my code points:

1. you can create a list from `a` to `b` using `list(range(a,b+1))` and you don't need while loop.
2. you can choose all elements from first in while body using `break` statement. if condition is False, so break loop, if not, go on and choose a new element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is due to the fact that every time it does not find the target element the list decreases by 1 and if the removed element is before the target element it will change index.

I think the only solution is to stop removing the wrong elements, this would guarantee the correct functioning of the program but would increase its execution times.